# Want to know the value of MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU

Tags: c#

I know that the default value of MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU is 12. I have read a number of articles like the one below:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx

But still, via code or some other way, I want to know the exact value of MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU. We run our application on .Net Framework 2.0

I know for .Net 4.0 and above, its easy using HostingEnvironment.MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU

Please help me out.

Regards,
Varun Shringarpure

Comment: Guys, can anyone help me out on this please?

Comment: It's in the blog post. Just look at the registry key/read the aspnet.config file as appropriate.